# cx-Freeze - Error when running frozen program from another machine

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I made a script in python to print something on Windows, using the `win32print` module. I froze it, using the following `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"include_msvcr":True,'includes':['win32print','win32ui']}

setup(name='scoate',
      version='0.1',
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      description='scoate la printer',
      executables=[Executable('sand2.py', base=base)]
      )
```

I ran the exe on my Windows 7, it runs fine. When I copied the program to my dad's Windows XP, it shoots the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "sand2.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Ghena\Desktop\tata\plot.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 539, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1692, in load_module
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here are the generated files:

```
library.zip
mfc100u.dll
msvcp100.dll
MSVCR100.dll
PIL._imaging.pyd
PIL._imagingft.pyd
python34.dll
sand2.exe
unicodedata.pyd
win32print.pyd
win32ui.pyd
_bz2.pyd
_hashlib.pyd
_lzma.pyd
```

Line 1 in `plot.py` says `"import win32print"`. But as you can see, it is present among the generated files. What is wrong?

PS If I erase the `'includes':[...]` from `setup.py` it's the same thing. I tried freezing it with `pyinstaller` and it worked ok on the other machine, but `pyinstaller` doesn't support `python3`.